# MySQL doesn't start

Tags: mysql, windows, webserver, xampp

I've installed [Portable Xampp](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) on my flashdrive.

Here is what I'm getting when I try to start MySQL on portable XAMPP server. (Apache starts without any fail)

[image]
And log looks like that

```
121003 22:07:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121003 22:07:31 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121003 22:07:31 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121003 22:07:31 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121003 22:07:31 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121003 22:07:31 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file \xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 is of different size 0 0 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
121003 22:07:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
121003 22:07:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
121003 22:07:31 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
121003 22:07:31 [ERROR] Aborting

121003 22:07:31 [Note] e:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

What am I missing? HOW to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you changed any parameter in php.ini or any core files before mysql shutdown

Comment: @gowri it happens in 1 sec. I can't even see mysql running indicator. No, I haven't change anything

Comment: I plugged in your error message to google and the first result?  http://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu

Comment: @BryanH I agree with you, but then again I must admin that it is a development tool in this context...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Stop MySQL
2. Make the configuration change to the log file size.
3. Delete both log files.
4. Start MySQL. It will complain about the lack of log files, but it'll create them and all will be well.

> ```
>     innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2560M
>     innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
>     innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
>     innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
>     innodb_thread_concurrency   = 16
>     innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
> ```

**move innodb old log files and restart the Mysql Server**

```
mv ib<filenames> ib<filenames>.old
```

Comment: doesn't help. same errors. no success

Comment: **move innodb old log files and restart the Mysql Server**

    mv ib<filenames> ib<filenames>.old

Comment: Paste here your innodb configuration!